# First & Follow, Arithmetic Expressions

Tags: grammar, puzzle

```
FIRST(A)  = { b, epsilon  }
FIRST(S) = { b, epsilon  }

FOLLOW(S)  = { a, $ }
FOLLOW(A) = { a, b, $ }
```

What is the Arithmetic Expressions for this First & Follow set?

Comment: Is there a programming application to this?

Comment: Looks like LL/LR/LALR parsing equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FIRST(X)` = the terminals which can appear first when trying parse the non-terminal `X`. If it can match an empty string, epsilon is also included.

`FOLLOW(X)` = the terminals which can appear immediately after the non-terminal `X`. This is a union of the FIRST-sets of all symbols appearing after `X` in any parsing rule.

Read more: [LL parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser)

The clues given are:

1. `FIRST(A)`, `FIRST(S)` ⇒ All of the derivations of `A` and `S` respectively, must either begin with the terminal `b`, or be zero-length.

   > `S` → `b` ... | ε
   >   `A` → `b` ... | ε
2. `FOLLOW(S)` ⇒ There must be some construction where `S` is followed by the terminal `a`, or a non-terminal which can begin with `a`. (Neither `A` nor `S` qualify).

   > `S` → `b` `S` `a` | ε
   >   `A` → `b` ... | ε
3. `FOLLOW(A)` ⇒ There must be some construction where `A` is followed by each of the terminals `a` and `b`, or some non-terminal which can begin with those.

   > `S` → `b` `S` `a` | ε
   >   `A` → `b` `A` `b` | `b` `A` `a` | ε
4. `FOLLOW(A)` ⇒ Assuming `S` is the start-symbol, `A` must appear at the end of some branch of `S`, possibly followed by other nullable non-terminals.

   > `S` → `b` `S` `a` | `A` | ε
   >   `A` → `b` `A` `b` | `b` `A` `a` | ε

   (NB. Adding `A` to `S` did not break the constraint on `FIRST(S)`)

We can make the grammar a little smaller:

> `S` → `b` `S` `a` | `A` | ε
>   `A` → `b` `A` `b` | ε

We can no longer generate strings like "`bbbabb`", but it does not violate the constraints.

Comment: You right, FIRST(A) appeared twice, i made correction. I need to make the simplest grammar created by these groups.

example: A->b | epsilon....